# syslogd writes one remote message into log file in 5 seconds

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udp, syslog

I'm using syslogd (package sysklogd) on Ubuntu VBox vm for logging messages from remote host: VBox vm Windows xp java application with log4j syslog appender. I send 10 messages with timeout 100 milliseconds, all ok, but syslogd writes them into log file very slow, 1 record in 5 seconds. I used wireshark on both virtual machines, all udp packages go without any timeout, so problem in syslog.

```
May 17 17:05:09 192.168.130.198 16:57:48,055 ...| Test message ¹0 
May 17 17:05:14 192.168.130.198 16:57:48,155 ...| Test message ¹1 
May 17 17:05:19 192.168.130.198 16:57:48,255 ...| Test message ¹2
```

All other messages seems to be cached by syslog.

Question:

How can I eliminate this delay? I'm going to write log messages from cluster of application servers into one log file. Does syslog able to process 500-1000 udp log messages in second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled upon this question after exactly the same problem, and subsequently found that it was due to delay and failure in reverse DNS lookup by the log server.

For `sysklogd`, a quick fix (without setting up a DNS server for internal network) which worked for me was adding an entry, e.g.

`192.168.130.198 any-hostname`

in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to figure out why syslog was lagging my router - this was the reason. In this case I just put the host (ie, the router) and reverse lookup in the bind zone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `syslog-ng` instead instead of `sysklogd`.

On the other hand, the problem may also come from a problem of time synchronization. Use ntp with both host.